# How can an app delete large files without using the Trash?

Tags: macos, trash

The App Store app "Trash Without" states the ability to permanently delete large files instantly, avoiding the OS X Trash entirely.  How can it do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Trash is just another directory in your user's home directory. So whenever you delete a file through "normal" means, it is merely moved to `~/.Trash`, from where it can be restored or finally deleted.

This is really just a safeguard. The trash is a concept that was invented much later than the principal operating system paradigm of deleting a file.

If you want to remove a file in Unix-like systems, you only need to call `rm <filename>`, and it is unlinked (through the system-internal `unlink` call). While the file may still be physically stored on the disk, its reference is lost, and therefore it is deleted.

Therefore, it's easy enough to bypass the Trash by simply `rm`ing a file.

Comment: Very good. That must be it. However, it indicates that the extra time and effort Mac Trash displays during "empty trash securely" is a ruse. But, due to your succinct explanation, I can't see it being any other way. An eternal snubbing.

Comment: "Secure" removal of a file involves overwriting the physical blocks of a file's data prior to unlinking, such that even if the link was rebuilt, or those blocks were subsequently recovered and examined there would be no remnant of the old data to be found, by less than forensic methods.